# DVD files not appear in file manager both windows and os x

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, filesystems, dvd, dvd-burning

Many thanks for reading.

I have a DVD - R containing a set of MRI images along with the viewer (GE MRI machine dvd write).
In my effort to browse the DVD it appears empty in both Apple and Windows Vista / 7 machine. 
Disk properties shows 0 used and 0 free (windows).
The friend that brought this to me,  told me that the MRI files are inside and the dvd media is good.
I have used Nero disk info utility and it reports that a track of 644MB is allocated .
This shows that files are inside which unfortunately I cannot browse.
Do you have any idea why this is happening and If I can somehow get the disk contents.

Many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The program [isobuster](http://www.isobuster.com/isobuster.php) allowed the browsing and the simple drag and drop movement of the DVD files, into the desktop of a windows machine.